# Parsing space indented data

Tags: python, parsing

I have some data that looks like YAML, but aint. Here is an example;

```
An instance of A
  objectID=123
  family=abc

An instance of A
  objectID=234
  family=bcd
  List of 4 X elements:
    An instance of X:
      objectID=222
      name=ccc
    An instance of X:
      objectID=333
```

And so on...

I need to find a way to make it looks more like this:

```
[
  {'name': 'An instance of A',
   'data': [
     {'objectID': 123,
      'family': 'abc'
     }
   ]
 },
 ...
```

I have tried to create some recursive function to parse this, but it ends up being a mess.

I'm not asking for a complete working example, but what is the best way to do this in python?
Self calling function? Using another lib (which I haven't found yet)? Using another language to help me and embed the whole thing in python?

Comment: You could try using a library like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a stack, and push and pop items from it as you find more or fewer levels of indentation; each level on the stack holds the indentation depth and the entry:

```
stack = [(0, {})]  # indentation level, top-level entry
entry = stack[-1][1]

for line in input:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue

    indentation = len(input) - len(input.lstrip())
    if indentation > stack[-1][0]:  # indented further? New entry
        entry = stack[-1][1]['data'] = {}
        stack.append((indentation, entry)) # push
    else:
        while indentation < stack[-1][0]:  # indentation dropped
            del stack[-1]       # pop
            entry = stack[-1][1]

    # process line and add to entry

result = stack[0][1]
```

Comment: That will fail when you get to the end of a composite which ends with a composite: it will only pop one thing off the stack instead of two (or more). You need to do it like python does, where you keep a stack of indents and pop the stack until you hit the previously used indent (or report an error, or try to guess what they meant if the new indent wasn't previously used.)

Comment: @rici: True, you'd need to include the indent count on the stack then. Updated my answer to do just that, and pop until the indentation level is matched again.